# Check and delete an existent wrapper - ibm db2

Tags: sql, plsql, db2, plsqldeveloper

I am new with PLSQL (IDM db2) and I am trying to check if a wrapper (MY_WRAPPER) exists and if it exists I want to delete it.

Following documentation, I found out a way to delete wrappers: `DROP WRAPPER MY_WRAPPER;`

The issue is that if the wrapper doesn't exist, I get this error:

```
[Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]  "MY_WRAPPER" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, ...
```

How can I implement a script to delete this wrapper if it exists and if not, no error should be returned?

SOLUTION:

```
BEGIN 
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.WRAPPERS WHERE WRAPNAME = 'MY_WRAPPER') 
  THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP WRAPPER MY_WRAPPER'; 
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: `BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.WRAPPERS WHERE ...) THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP WRAPPER ...'; END IF; END`. Try the complete statement on your own, show your code and the error message in case of failure.

Comment: I have implemented a solution. Can you comment if it looks good? I made some changes on your solution

Comment: It would look good, if you deleted extra `END` and changed `like` to `=`...

Comment: I made the changes. Typo :) Anyway we could chat?

Comment: You shouldn't use the default statement separator (`;`) at the end of a compound statement. It may or may not fail depending on the driver or other circumstances otherwise.

Comment: YOu are correct. Changed it